# Get value of Product id gives zero

Tags: php, prestashop, hook

I want this hook to work in category page where a list of products are displayed. The hook is placed in every product item.

I know it sounds uncommon but I have circumstances. Please I just need to solve how to get the product id in this hook?

```
public function hookDisplayProductInfoGlobal()
    {           
        $idProduct = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
        echo "Product id = ". $idProduct;
    }
```

result is **Product id = 0**

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `id_product` from the tpl where you are calling the hook, eg:
`{hook h='displayProductInfoGlobal' product=['id_product' => 123]}`

And now in your php take it in the params, eg:

```
public function hookDisplayProductInfoGlobal($params)
{           
    $idProduct = (int)$params['id_product'];
    echo "Product id = ". $idProduct;
}
```